Use a predefined array of string values against querySelectorAll, to perform a specific action
If I have a predefined array of string values, how can I see if any of them exist in the DOM via querySelectorAll and textContent?

//my array of predefined string values
let primaries = ["house", "people", "cat", "dog"];

let mTable = document.querySelectorAll("#mytable td font");

this is where I am stuck...I want to find any string from primaries against mTable. And if any string value is found, then perform a specific action (i.e. console.log("I found you"));
This is what I have so far but it only works for one element at a time. How can I expand my thought process..
var mPrimary = Array.from(
  mtable.querySelectorAll("td font")
).find((el) => el.textContent === "house");
if (mPrimary) {
  mPrimary.closest("tr").classList.add("d-none");
}


.find() will only return the first match. Don't you want all the matches?

Thank you for that tip! Yes I want to expand my thinking and try to find "any" match from the array of strings.

Use the Array.includes() method to search for the text in the array.
And use .filter() instead of .find() to get all the matching td's. Then you can use .forEach() to process all of them.
var mPrimary = Array.from(mtable.querySelectorAll("td font")
).filter(
  (el) => primaries.includes(el.textContent.trim())
);
mprimary.forEach(el => el.closest("tr").classList.add("d-none"));

I added .trim() so surrounding whitespace won't cause the match to fail.

Why not chain ? Also Array.from is more descriptive than the spread in my opinion

It would be so nice if all the array-like objects inherited all the array traversal methods. Regarding chaining, I chose to keep the original code's structure. Assigning names to inermediate values can make code easier to understand.

why looping twice?
mprimary.forEach(el => !primaries.includes(el.textContent.trim() && el.closest("tr").classList.add("d-none")) and avoid filter

That's another way to do it. Post it as an answer. @HagaiHarari

@HagaiHarari and even document.querySelectorAll("#mytable td font").forEach(el => !primaries.includes(el.textContent.trim() && el.closest("tr").classList.add("d-none")) since forEach IS supported by the collection returned by querySelectorAll
